# Celery beat not executing anything

Tags: python, redis, celery

I have a Celery task that is scheduled to run every 3 hours using Celery beat. However, nothing is executed, and I have zero logs in my celery beat container... Is there something wrong on my configs?
Any suggestions?

My stack:

```
python 3.7.0
celery==4.2.1
redis==3.4.1

redis-container: image "redis:5.0.9"
One celery worker container
One celery beat container
```

Please note that the three containers are in a docker swarm, and are thus in the same network.

My python script:

**init**.py

```py
from celery import Celery, signals

CELERY = Celery(
    my_project,
    backend="redis://redis:6379/1",
    broker="redis://redis:6379/1",
    include=["my_project.tasks", "my_project.other_tasks"],
)


CELERY.conf.update({"task_routes": {"my_project.tasks.*": {"queue": "my_queue"},
                                    "my_project.other_tasks.*": {"queue": "other_tasks"}},
                    "worker_hijack_root_logger": False,
                    "worker_log_format": "%(message)s",
                    "worker_redirect_stdouts": False
                    }
                   )


@signals.setup_logging.connect
def on_setup_logging(**kwargs):
    pass


CELERY.log.setup()
```

tasks.py

```py
from . import CELERY


@CELERY.on_after_finalize.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    """Setup the peridoci tasks

    :param sender: sender
    :param **kwargs: 

    """
    sender.add_periodic_task(10800, my_task.s())


@CELERY.task
def my_tasks(**kwargs):
    print("Hello world")
```

Entry point of celery worker. Please note that when I execute tasks directly in the container with task.apply_async(), it's working.

```
celery --loglevel=INFO -A my_project.tasks worker -Q my_queue -c 3
```

Entry point of celery beat. **I believe the problem comes from here**:

```
celery -A my_project.tasks beat -b redis://redis:6379/1 -l debug
```

Comment: So your worker and your beat are both in a separate container? Since you are using a localhost redis instance, the messages from your beat get put in a different redis instance than the ones from your worker and thus won't be picked up. You should use a redis instance outside of the containers that both the worker and the beat use.

Comment: I am using a redis container (not a localhost redis), and the three containers are in a docker swarm. Thus, they are connected by the Docker swarm. I will edit my question with this information

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that they way you configure Celery to create a periodic task will instruct it to send specified task to the default queue (conveniently named `celery`). Since you do not have worker(s) subscribed to this queue (your worker is subscribed to the `my_queue`) it will keep sending tasks, but they will not be executed, so you probably have quite many tasks in the `celery` queue that you may need to purge.

One way to fix it is to instruct Celery scheduler to send the task to the `my_queue` - for that you need to change tasks.py and have `sender.add_periodic_task(10800, my_task.s(), options={'queue': 'my_queue'})`

I never use add_periodic_task(), instead I recommend you to use [beat_schedule](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules) when you configure Celery.

Also, `celery --loglevel=INFO -A my_project.tasks worker -Q my_queue,celery -c 3` will make it work too, but you may not want that particular worker to be subscribed to the `celery` (default) queue...

Comment: Hello,
I tried to update my code adding options={'queue': 'my_queue'}, but it didn't change anything. Is there anything else I need to do ?

Comment: You have an alternative already, read the whole text...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the alternative solution. You say "celery --loglevel=INFO -A my_project.tasks worker -Q my_queue,celery -c 3 will make it work too, " , while it's exactly the command I have right now. Also, you say "you may not want that particular worker to be subscribed to the celery (default) queue...", while this worker is subscribed to my_queue and not the celery default queue.. Can you clarify this solution a little bit? 

Thanks a lot